# Angular 2 - Links from api data to open in new window

Tags: angular

I have some html coming from a string (from an api) but it doesn't follow any pattern or structure. I need to be able to force any link to open in a new window.

```
information: string = "<div>Hello this is the <a href="http://www.example.com">link</a> and there could be more links like <a href="http://www.example.com">this</a> - shocking</div>";

<div [innerHTML]="information"></div>
```

Any ideas? Please note that the html as presented here has to stay in tact, the Javascript has to force the links to open in a new window. Reason being is because the content is content managed by a user who won't know html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions could be using Pipe i.e.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'outgo'
})
export class OutgoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, ...args): any {
    return value.replace(/\<a/g, "<a target='_blank'");
  }
}
```

So your could would look a bit different:

```
<div [innerHTML]="information | outgo"></div>
```

This may cause duplicating `target` attribute if it already exists on link but it should not affect anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help that works great. I was trying to do it via a directive but it got very messy very quickly. This is much more simplified.